# Remove SelectedItem from TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, null, selecteditem

Is there a simple way to set a TreeView's SelectedItem to null or equivalent? Also, I need to do this in C# and not in XAML.

Best regards,

Gabriel

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Why do you need to null the SelectedItem?

Comment: I think he just wants to clear selection, maybe in dependence to another fields value, that user have to newly select a treeview node, so Karl gave the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what you mean

If you want to remove the item, use this:

```
treeView1.Items.Remove(treeView1.SelectedItem);
```

If you want to remove the selection from the treeview, use this:

```
((TreeViewItem)treeView1.SelectedItem).IsSelected = false;
```

Comment: `SelectedItem` is an `object` so you need to cast it.

Comment: What will you do if TreeView is data bound?

Comment: Of course, I didn't think about that you could deselect using IsSelected property. Silly of me, excellent answer. Works like a charm, cheers!

Comment: there was no hint to that in the question, so i guess he's building the treeview on his own ;)

Comment: Try to click on the deselected item and you will be surprised. Also try to switch to another window and then back to browser. The "deselected" item becomes selected

Answer (score 9):

All previous answers will be helpful when you build the TreeView explicitly using TreeViewItem(s). If you need a solution to clear selection when using ItemsSource, use the following code:

```
private static TreeViewItem FindTreeViewSelectedItemContainer(ItemsControl root, object selection)
{
    var item = root.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selection) as TreeViewItem;
    if (item == null)
    {
        foreach (var subItem in root.Items)
        {
            item = FindTreeViewSelectedItemContainer((TreeViewItem)root.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(subItem), selection);
            if (item != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return item;
}

// Example:
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (TV.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        var container = FindTreeViewSelectedItemContainer(TV, TV.SelectedItem);
        if (container != null)
        {
            container.IsSelected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to unselect what is selected?

I think you want something like this:

```
((TreeViewItem)tv.SelectedItem).IsSelected = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to quickly remove all Items?
If so, you can use

```
treeView1.Items.Clear();
```